# Total amount of sales in a month SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

Don't know if I overdid it with the normalization but there are 4 tables:

- Employee (ID, Name)
- Product (ID, Name, Price)
- Order_Details (ID, Employee_ID {FK}, Month, Year) -- time of purchase and which employee made the sale
- Order_Each_Product (OrderID {PK, FK}, ProductID {PK, FK}, Quantity) -- which product was purchased and how many of each product was purchased

I want something like this:

```
( Employee_Name, Month, Total_Sales_Made_In_That_Month_In_Dollar )
```

I think you can get the total of each order from 2 tables with something like:

```
SELECT SUM((Order_Each_Product.Quantity) * (Product.Price)) 
FROM Order_Each_Product 
INNER JOIN Product ON Order_Each_Product.ProductID = Product.ProductID
GROUP BY OrderID
```

But how do you group that again by Employee and get the SUM of the SUM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forpas beat me to it while I was writing the code!

```
SELECT
    Employee.Name, Year, Month, SUM(Quantity * Price) AS Total_Sales_In_Month
FROM 
    Order_Details

LEFT JOIN Employee
    ON (Order_Details.Employee_ID = Employee.ID)

LEFT JOIN Order_Each_Product
    ON (Order_Details.ID = Order_Each_Product.OrderID)

LEFT JOIN Product
    ON (Order_Each_Product.ProductID = Product.ID)

GROUP BY
    Employee.ID, Employee.Name, Year, Month
```

Just a tip also, what you are currently calling `Order_Details` and `Order_Each_Product` would normally be called `order_headers` and `order_lines` respectively.

Comment: You sir are a gift. I find yours super beginner friendly while i'm not familiar with Forpas's from employee e... But my problems are solved. Also thank you for the final tip.

Comment: @SwedishPotato, thanks! :) Don't forget to upvote and mark answered. And just to explain Forpas's code, he was using what's called a table alias and omitting the optional `AS`. In full you would write `FROM Employee AS e`, and from that point it allows you to refer to the Employee table by the name `e`.

Answer (score 1):

Join all the tables and group by the employee's id, name, Year and Month:

```
select
  e.name,
  od.Year,
  od.Month,
  sum(oep.quantity * p.price) Total_Sales_Made_In_That_Month_In_Dollar
from employee e 
inner join order_details od on od.employee_id = e.id
inner join order_each_product oep on oep.orderid = od.id
inner join product p on p.id = oep.productid
group by e.id, e.name, od.Year, od.Month
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I see instead of FROM Employee you wroted FROM Employee e. Maybe there's a keyword for that last e? It was super helpful anyway. Thank you sir!

Comment: `e` is an alias for the `Employee` table. You can find aliasing also with the AS keyword: Employee AS e.

Comment: @SwedishPotato I understand that you are a beginner in SQL, so you need an advice: you must learn to use aliases, in most cases you can't code without them.